# como puedo insertar cuando se presione un botón sin necesidad de recargar la vista laravel

Tags: laravel

cuando presione comenzar atención que cambie el estado de la base de datos de espera a en proceso eso lo tengo con un enum, la cosa es que no debe actualizar la pagina al momento de cambiar el estado, en el controlador tengo el siguiente código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  public function attentionespera(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->get('id');
    $attentionlist = Attentionlist::where('id',$id)->first();
    $attentionlist->status = 'espera';
    $attentionlist->update();
    return redirect('/attentions');
}
public function attentionproceso(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->get('id');
    $attentionlist = Attentionlist::where('id',$id)->first();
    $attentionlist->status = 'proceso';
    $attentionlist->update();
    return redirect('/attentions');
}
public function attentionfinalizado(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->get('id');
    $attentionlist = Attentionlist::where('id',$id)->first();
    $attentionlist->status='finalizado';
    $attentionlist->update();
    return redirect('/attentions');
}
```

Comment: Intenta hacerlo con ajax

Comment: ya tengo un ajax en el cual capturo los datos para que rellene el numero de atencion en ese ajax paso todos los datos la cosa es que no se como hacer en la vista para mandarle el id al boton y actualizar la base de datos cambiando el estado sin que actualice la vista